# Flutter-Firebase Continuous triggering of the method

Tags: flutter, firebase

Have a nice day. I don't think there is an error in my code but there is something ridiculous.

I have a method that returns all registered days of the user in firebase:

```
@override
  Future<List<SporGunleriModel>> getAlldays(String userID) async {
    QuerySnapshot query = await _firestoreDB
        .collection("günler")
        .doc(userID + " GUN")
        .collection("gün")
        //.where("kullanici", isEqualTo: userID)
        .get();

List<SporGunleriModel> tumGunler = [];

for (DocumentSnapshot tekGun in query.docs) {
  var _tekGun =
      SporGunleriModel.fromMap(tekGun.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
  tumGunler.add(_tekGun);
  print("getALLdays tetic"); 
}

return tumGunler;
```

This is triggering on the home page:

```
child: FutureBuilder<List<SporGunleriModel>>(
            future: _usermodel.getAlldays(_usermodel.user!.userID),
            builder: (context, liste) {
              if (liste.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } else {
                var listeokey = liste.data;
                if (listeokey!.length > 0) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: GridView.builder(
                      gridDelegate:
                          const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                              maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                              childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                              crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                              mainAxisSpacing: 15),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        var anlikdata = listeokey[index];
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
                                .push(MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => GymSayfDetayli(
                                  sporgunleriIndexlI: anlikdata),
                            ));
                          },
```

It works without error, but whenever I click on Form, TextButton style widgets in my program, this method is triggered. No matter which text writing widget I press, in the above method `print("getALLdays tetic");` triggers and outputs.

> I/flutter ( 2075): getALLdays tetic

What I want to know is if this is normal. So every time I operate inside `child: FutureBuilder<List<SportGunleriModel>>` will the `getAlldays` method be triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it’s convenient, it’s not recommended to put an API call in a `build()` method.

Flutter calls the `build()` method every time it needs to change anything in the view, and this happens surprisingly often. The fetchAlbum() method, if placed inside `build()`, is repeatedly called on each rebuild causing the app to slow down.

Storing the `getAlldays()`  result in a state variable ensures that the Future is executed only once and then cached for subsequent rebuilds.

Call the `getAlldays()` method in either the `initState()` or `didChangeDependencies()` methods.

Refer the flutter docs below for the code implementation:
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#4-fetch-the-data

Comment: Got it, thank you, but I'm using `Provider` and I'm using it under the build method to get context. (`final _usermodel = Provider.of<UserModel>(context);`)Do you have any suggestions for this?